# En una lista de PackageManager como obtener la ruta de un app en especial con una seleccion

Tags: android

Como están espero que bien. MI problema es el siguiente he creado una lista de app en un listView usando los métodos de PackageManager y PackegeInfo, pero me he preguntado como encontrar la ruta de ese app mediante una seleccion y la selecciona mostrara la ruta de esa mediante un OnItemClickListener. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Tu descripción deja mucho que desear, prueba con esto y adaptalo a que coja el index de la lista del setOnItemClickListener de la lista.

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> info = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
 String ruta = info.get(0).sourceDir;
```

Para más info consulta la documentación que no muerde :D
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias la voy a probar y adaptar para ver si me hace el trabajo. En serio muchas gracias.

Comment: Te pregunto en mi app cree nos List<ApplicationInfo> debo ese método enlazarlos con los que que tengo o solo crear un nuevo método como el que me distes.

Comment: Y algo mas y lo siento por las molestias, pero como dice el dicho "Hombre preparado llega lejos". TAmbien tengo un package manager ya creado no hay una forma que yo adapte ese package manager al metodo que mi diste, porque en este pakage manager se almacenan o ese codigo es universal y no da problema con la existencia de lo ya mencionado.

Comment: Utiliza lo que te he pasado ya que coge el de Android. Que sera el mismo que utilizas tu

Comment: Si te ha servido acepta pa respuesta por válida

Comment: Si me sirvió el método, pero hay un problema me busca la ruta de app, pero no son las que se muestran en el listView si no app del sistema.Si me ayuda te lo agradecería.

Comment: Si tienes un adapter añade en cada view .setTag("con el nombre del paquete de al app correspondiente"); y recorres la lista que ya tiene y com y te recorres la lista que ya tienes con todas lass app y vas comparando en onClick que `view.getTag().equal( info.get(i).packageName)` si es correcto muestras la ruta y la otra solución un poco más limpia que recorrer todo el array sería esta: `PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
String s = getPackageName();
PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;`

Donde la variable s deberia ser el nombre del paquete de la app

Comment: Algo que creo que debí comentar es que mi app quiero que muestre las app del usuario y busque su ruta.Pero muchas gracias por tu método y si tienes un mejor manera para lo que yo quiero te lo agradecería.